# Where does this white dust come from?

Tags: pcb

I have a PCB from a humidifier which ceased to work. It could be water damage but I am not sure.

[image]

I sm unsure if it is the transformer or some capacitor.

Please advise if I can repair or if it is better to take the good parts and throw away the rest.

Comment: "Humidifier."  There's a good chance that the dust is from the water, especially if it is an ultrasonic humidifier.

Comment: If the caps would have leaked you'd usually see some damage to the top of them. And the transformer is pretty much just copper around some other metal core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This white dust is caused by water impurities, often like limestone, that gets vaporized by the ultrasonic thingy and blown around. You can often see it on the floor around humidifiers.

It's unlikely to be the cause of the damage though. That board seems to be a basic power supply, you can check the output if you have any voltage out. Visually it seems fine, so it's probably the ultrasonic transducer.

You can try to put some vinegar for a few days on the transducer (inside the water compartment) if it's due to limestone clug-up that would dissolve it.